# TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of null Vuejs Router

Tags: vue.js

I have a router like this

```
{
          path: 'user',
          redirect: '/user',
          name: 'user',
          component: {
            render(c) {
              return c('router-view', {
                on: {
                  showLoading: function (val) {
                    this.$emit('showLoading', val)
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          },
```

when run that router I got an error

> "[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "showLoading": "TypeError:
>   Cannot read property '$emit' of null"

.
As I googled, it seem like I can't use `this.$emit` inside router. I want to emit event `'showLoading'`, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using arrow function that is not defining its own `this`.

```
showLoading: val => {
   this.$emit('showLoading', val)
}
```

[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)